BigQuery SA360 Data Transfer Says Custom Columns Do Not Exist But They Do
I am trying to create an SA360 data transfer into BigQuery using the UI.
In the Custom Columns field I am using the following configuration.
[
    {
        "id": "123456789",
        "destination_table_name": [
            "Conversion", 
            "AdGroupConversionActionAndDeviceStats", 
            "CampaignConversionActionAndDeviceStats" 
        ],
        "bigquery_column_name": "my_custom_col_name"
    }
]

I recieve the error code 3: Custom column with id '123456789' does not exist.
Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

in your custom field, can you verify if the '123456789' can be found? you might have a typo error or a different name for it.

@marky The custom column definitely exists, no typos. I have verified it's existents in SA360 and by pulling it using Python. It is just with the Data Transfer job that this problem occurs

can you also check the permissions for the SA360 and BQ? as this also can affect the output.
